# How do I encode/decode JSON and preserve the language?

Tags: wordpress, json

We have built site in local language ("GUJRATI") - language, and i need to create JSON-web services for this wp-sites , and i did it but please can any one tell us how to encode or decode it with preserve languages .

Encoding Data is :

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "count": 4,
    "count_total": 4,
    "pages": 1,
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "type": "post",
            "slug": "%e0%aa%b6%e0%aa%bf%e0%aa%b5%e0%aa%b0%e0%aa%82%e0%aa%9c%e0%aa%a8%e0%ab%80-%e0%aa%9a%e0%aa%be%e0%aa%b0-%e0%aa%b0%e0%aa%b8%e0%ab%8d%e0%aa%a4%e0%aa%be-%e0%aa%aa%e0%aa%be%e0%aa%b8%e0%ab%87-%e0%aa%a4",
            "url": "http://localhost/webservices/%e0%aa%b6%e0%aa%bf%e0%aa%b5%e0%aa%b0%e0%aa%82%e0%aa%9c%e0%aa%a8%e0%ab%80-%e0%aa%9a%e0%aa%be%e0%aa%b0-%e0%aa%b0%e0%aa%b8%e0%ab%8d%e0%aa%a4%e0%aa%be-%e0%aa%aa%e0%aa%be%e0%aa%b8%e0%ab%87-%e0%aa%a4/",
            "status": "publish",
            "title": "શિવરંજની ચાર રસ્તા પાસે ત્રણ લૂંટારુંઓએ ગોળીબાર કરીને રૂ. 1.04 કરોડની લૂંટ ચલાવી",
            "title_plain": "શિવરંજની ચાર રસ્તા પાસે ત્રણ લૂંટારુંઓએ ગોળીબાર કરીને રૂ. 1.04 કરોડની લૂંટ ચલાવી",
            "content": "<p>આજે સવારે શિવરંજની ચાર રસ્તા પાસે ત્રણ લૂંટારુંઓએ જાહેરમાં ગોળીબાર કરીને રૂ. 1.04 કરોડની લૂંટ ચલાવી હતી. લૂંટારુઓએ પહેલા તો હવામાં ગોળીબાર કર્યો હતો. પછી આઇટેનમાં આવેલા હિતેષ ઝવેરીને ગોળીથી વિંધી નાંખ્યા હતા અને બે બેગ લઈને ફરાર થઈ રહ્યા હતા. આ દરમિયાન ફિલ્મની જેમ રાજેન્દ્રભાઈ પટેલ ત્રાટક્યા હતા અને લૂંટારુંઓ સાથે ઝપાઝપી કરી હતી. તેમજ લૂંટારુંઓને પથ્થર મારીને ભગાડી મૂક્યા હતા.ત્રણેય લૂંટારુંઓ પાસે રિવોલ્વર હતી અને તેઓ તો ખુલ્લેઆમ અમારી પર પણ ગોળીઓ વરસાવી રહ્યા હતા. ઝપાઝપીમાં એક લૂંટારુંની બંદૂક પળી ગઈ હતી. તેમજ એક લૂંટારુંની ગરમ ટોપી પણ અમે કાઢી નાંખી હતી. આ પછી મેં પથ્થરનો ઘા કર્યો હતો. આ જપ્પાજપ્પી દરમિયાન તેમને પકડાઇ જવાનો ડર લાગતાં તેઓ પલ્સર પર શ્યામલ ચાર રસ્તા તરફ ભાગી ગયા હતા.</p>\n",
            "excerpt": "<p>આજે સવારે શિવરંજની ચાર રસ્તા પાસે ત્રણ લૂંટારુંઓએ જાહેરમાં ગોળીબાર કરીને રૂ. 1.04 કરોડની લૂંટ ચલાવી હતી. લૂંટારુઓએ પહેલા તો હવામાં ગોળીબાર કર્યો હતો. પછી આઇટેનમાં આવેલા હિતેષ ઝવેરીને ગોળીથી વિંધી નાંખ્યા હતા અને બે બેગ લઈને ફરાર થઈ રહ્યા હતા. આ દરમિયાન ફિલ્મની જેમ રાજેન્દ્રભાઈ પટેલ ત્રાટક્યા હતા અને લૂંટારુંઓ સાથે ઝપાઝપી કરી હતી. [&hellip;]</p>\n",
            "date": "2014-01-16 07:03:22",
            "modified": "2014-01-16 07:03:22",
            "categories": [],
            "tags": [],
            "author": {
                "id": 1,
                "slug": "admin",
                "name": "admin",
                "first_name": "",
                "last_name": "",
                "nickname": "admin",
                "url": "",
                "description": ""
            },
            "comments": [],
            "attachments": [],
            "comment_count": 0,
            "comment_status": "open",
            "custom_fields": {}
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "type": "post",
            "slug": "web-services",
            "url": "http://localhost/webservices/web-services/",
            "status": "publish",
            "title": "web services",
            "title_plain": "web services",
            "content": "<p>this is test description</p>\n",
            "excerpt": "<p>this is test description</p>\n",
            "date": "2014-01-16 06:30:01",
            "modified": "2014-01-16 06:30:01",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "slug": "web",
                    "title": "web",
                    "description": "",
                    "parent": 0,
                    "post_count": 1
                }
            ],
            "tags": [],
            "author": {
                "id": 1,
                "slug": "admin",
                "name": "admin",
                "first_name": "",
                "last_name": "",
                "nickname": "admin",
                "url": "",
                "description": ""
            },
            "comments": [],
            "attachments": [],
            "comment_count": 0,
            "comment_status": "open",
            "custom_fields": {}
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "type": "post",
            "slug": "lorem-ipsum",
            "url": "http://localhost/webservices/lorem-ipsum/",
            "status": "publish",
            "title": "lorem ipsum",
            "title_plain": "lorem ipsum",
            "content": "<p>Lorem ipsum a lorem Lorem ipsum a loremLorem ipsum a loremLorem ipsum a loremLorem ipsum a loremLorem ipsum a lorem vLorem ipsum a lorem Lorem ipsum a lorem Lorem ipsum a lorem Lorem ipsum a lorem</p>\n",
            "excerpt": "<p>Lorem ipsum a lorem Lorem ipsum a loremLorem ipsum a loremLorem ipsum a loremLorem ipsum a loremLorem ipsum a lorem vLorem ipsum a lorem Lorem ipsum a lorem Lorem ipsum a lorem Lorem ipsum a lorem</p>\n",
            "date": "2014-01-16 06:28:29",
            "modified": "2014-01-16 06:28:29",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "slug": "test",
                    "title": "test",
                    "description": "",
                    "parent": 0,
                    "post_count": 1
                }
            ],
            "tags": [],
            "author": {
                "id": 1,
                "slug": "admin",
                "name": "admin",
                "first_name": "",
                "last_name": "",
                "nickname": "admin",
                "url": "",
                "description": ""
            },
            "comments": [],
            "attachments": [],
            "comment_count": 0,
            "comment_status": "open",
            "custom_fields": {}
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "post",
            "slug": "hello-world",
            "url": "http://localhost/webservices/hello-world/",
            "status": "publish",
            "title": "Hello world!",
            "title_plain": "Hello world!",
            "content": "<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!</p>\n",
            "excerpt": "<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!</p>\n",
            "date": "2014-01-16 05:09:08",
            "modified": "2014-01-16 05:09:08",
            "categories": [],
            "tags": [],
            "author": {
                "id": 1,
                "slug": "admin",
                "name": "admin",
                "first_name": "",
                "last_name": "",
                "nickname": "admin",
                "url": "",
                "description": ""
            },
            "comments": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Mr WordPress",
                    "url": "http://wordpress.org/",
                    "date": "2014-01-16 05:09:08",
                    "content": "<p>Hi, this is a comment.<br />\nTo delete a comment, just log in and view the post&#039;s comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.</p>\n",
                    "parent": 0
                }
            ],
            "attachments": [],
            "comment_count": 1,
            "comment_status": "open",
            "custom_fields": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Looks like you want to ensure it's encoded in at least UTF-8, if not UTF-16. Set the header on the API output script.

Comment: OK, does it work? Or not?

Comment: Then what is the problem?